# Xamarin Forms Access ViewModel Property in XAML

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms, selecteditem

How do I access a property of my ViewModel in XAML?

I am trying to enable a button only if a ListView has an item selected.  The selected item is data bound to SelectedCar in my ViewModel.  Now, I want to check if SelectedCar is null and if it is, disable button; otherwise enable it.

I tried something like this

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">   
    <ListView x:Name="lvwCars" ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}"
      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
         <Label Text="{Binding PlateNumber}" />
         <Label Text="{Binding OwnerName}" />    
        </StackLayout>
       </ViewCell>
      </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"> 
    <Button x:Name="btnBack" 
            Text="Back" 
            Command="{Binding BackClickCommand}"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnNext" 
            Text="Next" 
            IsEnabled="False"
            Command="{Binding ConfirmClickCommand}">
     <Button.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger TargetType="Button" 
       Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyCarsViewModel}, Path=SelectedCarProperty}" Value="null">
       <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
      </DataTrigger>
     </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: have you tried "{Binding SelectedCar}"?

Comment: It is right there in the provided code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `converter` (a class that implements IValueConverter) because you have the data but you need to bind to a property in another format, you have an object that can have a value (be different than null) or be null, so , you need to implement a converter like this:

```
public class ObjectToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value != null;
        }       

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then you can use that converter in your code:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"> 
<StackLayout.Resources>
  <conv:ObjectToBoolConverter x:Key="Null2bool" />
</StackLayout.Resources>    
<Button x:Name="btnBack" 
            Text="Back" 
            Command="{Binding BackClickCommand}"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnNext" 
            Text="Next" 
            IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedCar,Converter={StaticResource Null2bool}}"
            Command="{Binding ConfirmClickCommand}">
    </Button>
</StackLayout>
```

## Don't forget to import your converter's namespace in order to use in XAML

In this example, I used `conv:` as alias, so you need to place this in your page declaration on top:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Your.Converter.Namespace;assembly=Your.Assembly.Name"
```

For example, if your project is CarsMobile, and you have `CarsMobile, CarsMobile.Droid and CarsMobile.iOS,` and you put your converter class in a folder called `Converters` (*CarsMobile\Converters\ObjectToBoolConverter*) so your xmlns should look like this:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:CarsMobile.Converters;assembly=CarsMobile"
```

> **Reference** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: Above in Convert, you mean value != null right?  There is no input.  And also, where is "conv" comming from you added in StackLayout.Resources?

Comment: Oh you're right, sorry. I only have a notepad right now :)

Comment: `conv:` is the namespace where you place your converter , you need to import in order to use it in XAML

Comment: This will enable the button as you suggest, thanks.  But now the selection in list view stays.  How do I clear that selection so that button gets disabled again?  Thanks

Comment: Havent figured out the last point yet but thanks for your grat answer and help on majority of it Jesus!